# Load and Check Total Loss / Validation accuracy of Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I didn't find any answers to the following question:

Is there a way to print the trained model accuracy, total model loss and model evaluation accuracy after loading the saved trained Keras model?

```
from keras.models import load_model
m = load_model.load("lstm_model_01.hd5")
```

I checked all the callable methods of `m` but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model is really a graph with weights and that's all that gets saved. You have to evaluate the restored model on data to get predictions and from that you'll obtain an accuracy.

Comment: Ah! Got it. I was kinda hoping there was any other way to get the training loss or validation accuracy from the saved model. Thank you. If there is really no other way then I guess, I can just accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas save your model fit results as follows:

```
history = model.fit(input_train, y_train,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=128,
                    validation_split=0.2)
```

And use pickle to dump it (i.e. history) out. There you will see the training loss or validation accuracy from the model. You can load it back anytime.